# Have functions work outside the loop with 404 override

Tags: wp-query, templates, redirect, 404-error

I need to override the 404 code for a very specific scenario and it's not yet fully working.

I am linking day archives with `rel=prev/next`, and the chain is supposed to be intact start-to-end. For this reason, at least one post needs to be published everyday, best right at midnight. This should not be a problem editorially, with at least 10 posts being expected even on a slow news day.

However, accidents may happen - like downtime or unwarranted deletions or whatnot. Even in these cases, things should be repaired from the publishing end as soon as noticed (with at least one post forth/backdated to cover for the empty day).

Still, I wouldn't want the prev/next chain to ever be broken, so I'm thinking this as the ultimate fallback - ideally never triggered.

I have added the following to the functions.php template:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'empty_day', 0 );
function empty_day() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->post_count == 0 && $wp_query->query['day'] ) {
    status_header( '200' );
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        $wp_query->is_day = true;
        $wp_query->is_date = true;
        $wp_query->is_archive = true;
    }
}
```

It works nicely redirecting the empty page to the archive template, prev/next tags in place.

However, functions stop working outside the loop completely (no return), so I can't [`get_the_time`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) nor [`get_the_date`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) to output anything.

I already tried the solutions suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104991/preventing-404-error-on-empty-date-archive) or [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/empty-archives-returning-404), but they still fail to get the date with the `template_redirect` filter or redirect the template altogether with `404_template`.

Any Idea on how to have them working again?

Answer (score 1):

The timing of relevant parts of the process is following:

1. Query executes and fetches posts (or in this case *no* posts)
2. `template_redirect` fires
3. Template file is determined from query variables and loaded

When you change query variables in `template_redirect` you change template choice (which you observe), but you still *have no posts in query*.

The functions still work, they just *don't have a post* to work on.

It's quite a peculiar case, because which posts would you *expect* in an archive that is 404 and has no posts?

I am not sure without playing with such a setup but I would probably try to redirect "ahead" rather than "fake" valid page out of 404.

Comment: Indeed, I later found how this guy created a whole dummy post as well, but I tried and still it didn't work.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18190

Answer (score 1):

Got the job done by building a "private" time function to work with:

```
function my_date() { {
$day = get_query_var( 'day' );
$monthnum = get_query_var( 'monthnum' );
$year = get_query_var( 'year' );
$my_date = $year.'-'.$monthnum.'-'.$day;
} return $my_date; }
```

Now when I call this, it outputs fine.

Comment: Glad that you were able to solve your own question. Be sure to mark your answer as resolved in the next two days.